# How to record tracked position with Vuforia image target in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, model-view

I want to record tracked model view matrix per frame.
When tracking successfully, Vuforia would set camera and image target's gameobject position.
So I want to merge model view matrix of camera and gameobject.

```
Matrix4x4 cameraToWorld = perspCam.cameraToWorldMatrix;
Matrix4x4 worldToLocal = imgTarget.transform.worldToLocalMatrix;
Matrix4x4 cameraToLocal = cameraToWorld * worldToLocal;
```

Then, I set gameobject position, rotation and scale by cameraToLocal.
However, the image target's gameobject can't overlap on the correct place.
Where did I go wrong in my calculation?
OR is there better method to get one model view matrix from camera to gameobject?
Vuforia version : 9.8
World Center Mode : Deivece

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing too much of matrices you could achieve manually what you want using e.g.

```
var relativePosition = perspCam.transform.InverseTransformPoint(imageTarget.transform.position);
var relativeRotation = Quaternion.Inverse(perspCam.transform.rotation) * imageTarget.transform.rotation;
```

So that later you would get the same results relative to the camera again using

```
someObject.transform.position = perspCam.transform.TransformPoint(relativePosition);
someone to.transform.rotation = perspCam.transform.rotation * relativeRotation;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it. It works but it's camera still should use position and rotation which vuforia set. I want to set camera position and rotation with zero and only set value on gameObject. Is there other method? Thanks again!!